# Recurring billing with Rails - what are my options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant

Before jumping in I'd like to know what all of my options are, and, if possible their pros and cons.

The two I know of are using ActiveMerchant, or the paypal_recurring gem, but will they satisfy these requirements?

- Ability to accommodate monthly and annual billing
- Ability to suspend, cancel accounts etc
- Deal with out-of-date card details or failed payments

The to-do list for the paypal_recurring gem includes 'adding support for IPN' - how will not having this impact functionality?

I know there is the railskit SaaS but I'd rather code something myself as the railskit is still on 3.2.1.

I know there are services like cheddergedder/chargify etc, but do they tie you in? Are they US only? Are they worth considering - or are they usually just aimed at non-developers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just finished going through this, so I'll try to shed some light on your options. I ended up using Paypal Express Checkout for all recurring purchases through Paypal. We had a custom-rolled recurring billing setup that charges a customer's credit card monthly through [Authnet](http://authorize.net), but had to switch because we needed an international solution, and Paypal was one of the only ones that supported the currencies we needed, and wasn't entirely a nightmare to code.

You can use ActiveMerchant for recurring billing with [this](http://rayvinly.com/articles/2009/02/20/paypal-recurring-billing-with-activemerchant-in-ruby-on-rails/) plugin, though keep in mind that it is not officially a part of ActiveMerchant, and therefore is subject to break if ActiveMerchant changes how it handles certain things. Because of that, I ended up using the [paypal-recurring](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring) to handle communication through Paypal, and then rolled my own IPN parser, with help from [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing). Another link that helped me a lot was [this](http://ianpurton.com/adding-paypal-subscriptions-to-your-rails-application), though all the `:txn_type` values ended up being different.

With regards to that last link, here are the 4 `:txn_type`s that I specifically watch out for:

1. `express_checkout` - first postback.
2. `recurring_payment_profile_created` - sent on first postback when the user first subscribes.
3. `recurring_payment_profile_cancel` - sent if user cancels subscription from Paypal's site.
4. `recurring_payment` - Money has been transferred to your account. This is what I wait for before I renew their subscription on a monthly. This post also comes with `payment_status`, which needs to be `completed`.

The other stuff you mentioned, like handling failed payments and out-of-date cards, is handled through your Paypal account.

Just a word of warning - the only reason I ended up using Paypal is because it is universally recognized and trusted, and it accepted international currencies. There is an enormous amount of documentation on their site, and most of it is redundant, confusing, and entirely too long. My recommendation is to make sure you really want/need to deal with recurring payments, as they are difficult to implement correctly and can be more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan. I had a quick chat with @fnando earlier (author of paypal_recurring gem) and he gave me some tips on handling failed cards - it's too big to paste here but happy to email you if you want to take a look (@astonj on twitter) but basically if the ipn.type is equal to "recurring_payment_failed" then you can just handle that by firing off an email or flagging it up on their account. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I would very much appreciate it if you could email that to me! My email is listed in my profile. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, do you have an idea how to use encryption with Paypal-recurring gem ? I know about the cmd and encrypted options when using encrypted orders and paypal certificate, but, I don't know how to do it with Paypal-recurring, can you help me please ?

Comment: HTTPS encrypts the entire request, so that should be all you need. There's nothing specific to `paypal-recurring` that needs to be done - just make sure you're serving out HTTPS requests.

Comment: It's `recurring_payment_profile_canceled`, not cancel. Available variables can be found here:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Comment: @A4J can you please post via gist please. As I terribly need to look at the solution. Have tried multiple things that doesn't really work. Thanks

Comment: @JackieChan I ended up not using it, as there was no easy way for people to to change to a different plan (has to be cancelled then a new one created). Unfortunately I no longer have the conversation with Fnando anywhere - sorry.

Comment: Hi there, I know this is an old post, but, if someone reads this, are these the only `txn_types` I should be aware? is there one for `not enough funds`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently looking at Ryan Bates example of Stripe. They are a California based company that uses/offers the features you have listed.

www.stripe.com

They only charge when you receive money. I think that they are 3% plus $0.30 per successful transaction. Much better than some other companies that have a monthly minimum. Right now you have to have a bank in the USA to use their services as a merchant. However, anyone can use your site with out of the country credit cards.

Comment: I can't use stripe :( am based in the UK.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't notice from your question. Bummer cause they look pretty solid.

Comment: Yeah they would be my first choice if they were available here - wish they'd hurry up and come here!

Comment: @BradMace Thank you for catching/flagging the editing user in question here. I am fixing their old edits now, too.

Comment: Stripe is [now available in the UK](https://stripe.com/blog/introducing-stripe-uk).

Answer (score 0):

The SaaS Kit is now tested with Rails 3.2.2. :)  It doesn't support IPN yet, but it's on to the todo list.  With all the info here in one spot, I suppose I have no excuse not to get it done. :)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - I might email you some questions if that's ok? (PS you need to update the features tab as it still says Rails 3.1.1)